# Date Format Like "Monday, December 10" wrong showing in ios 5.1

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5

I am using below code.

```
NSString * weekdayString = [[self date] descriptionWithLocale:@"%A"];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",weekdayString,[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[self date]]];
NSArray * components = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",[components objectAtIndex:0],[components objectAtIndex:1]];
```

it's working fine in simulator and ios 6.0 but it's not showing as expected in ios 5.1 in device(iPad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NSDate -descriptionWithLocale`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/descriptionWithLocale%3a) is documented to take an `NSLocale`; you're passing an `NSString` and therefore relying on undocumented behaviour.

It's also unclear what you're trying to achieve with the splitting into components — presumably you've assumed that the NSDateFormatterShortStyle will always have a comma in it? That also isn't guaranteed by the documentation.

What you probably want to do is just set a custom date format string. From the title of your post it looks like you probably want `EEEE, MMMM dd`. So e.g.

```
// see QA1480 re: en_US_POSIX
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd"];
dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[self date]];
```

[QA1480](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html) addresses an issue that can cause `NSDateFormatter` silently to adapt your date formatter internally.